# static void Client script

Tags: c#, asp.net, static, clientscript

I have a method in an aspx web page which is accessed from another non webpage .cs class. This method contains a ClientScript to create a popup.

I get this error below when trying to make it a static.

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.ClientScript.get'

So I am wondering if there is a way to access this method from another .cs class or a solution.

Basically when an error trips on the .cs class I want to display a popup that says the error.

```
  public static void message(string popupinformation)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "popupinformation", true);
    }
```

In .cs

```
AddUI.message("alert('Error can not add information');");
```

Comment: post the code of both methods

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Can you tell / write which code is in the aspx.cs and which one a 'non-webpage'? also, what is AddUI, a class, an instance of a class, etc...

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** - You need to add `"System.web"` reference in that library.

I understand that, you have a separated cs file in some another library that invokes a function sitting in asp.net webform. If that is true, then how you are calling that function because it will be inside a page class which inherits from `system.web.ui.page`.

Lets assume you have make it work by placing that in `App_Code`. Then used that class say `Web_work.cs` in some other library say `lib.cs`.

To use `ClientScript...` in the library with `lib.cs` you need to add `"System.web"` reference in that library.

Best practice is to do all validation in library, but use such kind of display method in webform only. Take an example, lets say you want to use windows form now, which uses `MessageBox.Show`, in that case your library needs change with current approach.